# JWT gives JsonWebTokenError "invalid token"

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have used `jsonwebtoken` for token verification in my Node Application .
Here `jwt.sign` works perfectly . But when `jwt.verify` gives following error

> "auth": false,
>       "message": {
>           "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
>           "message": "invalid token"
>       }
>   }

Here is my Post and Get Router

```
router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
    const body = _.pick(req.body,['username','email_id','name','college','password','dob','gender','city','joinedOn','bio']);
    User.findOne({'username':body.username},function(err,user){
        if(err){
            res.status(404).send(err)
        }else if(user){
            res.status(404).send('User with Username Exists')
        }else{
            var user = new User(body);
            user.save().then((user) => {
                var token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username},'secret', {
                    "algorithm": "HS256",
                    expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                  });
                  res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
              }, (e) => {
                res.status(400).send(e)
              })
        }
    })

});

router.get('/me', VerifyToken, function(req, res) {

    User.findOne({username:req.username}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("No user found.");
        res.status(200).send(user);
      });

});
```

Below is verifyToken Function

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  var token =  req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (!token)
    return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });
    console.log(token)
  jwt.verify(token,'secret', function(err, decoded) {
    if (err)
    return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: err }); 
    //req.username = decoded.username;
    console.log(decoded)
    next();
  });
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong in my program .Any suggestions would be appreciated .
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My Code is true . The mistake I was doing that I was giving access token with **double quote("token")** in Postman. That's why postman was giving me following error

> "auth": false, "message": { "name": "JsonWebTokenError", "message": "invalid token" } }

Comment: Thank you for making this mistake and saving me some time (:

Comment: I was using in cookies and req.cookies.token returns token in "" (double quotes) so JSON.parse(token) was the solution

Answer (score 48):

If you are passing in a token to your jwt.verify function like so `Bearer *************....`, ensure to split the token first before passing it in to jwt by doing

`const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
jwt.verify(token)`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you ! That's it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Basically the token should not have brearer information. When I stripped it out it started working as expected.

For instance:

Failed when I used `brearer *************....`

Worked when I used `*************....`

Comment: This is wrong. Adding Bearer to auth header is a standarised practise and helps secure it

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error because I persisted the token in localStorage with `JSON.stringify`, which adds two double quotes to the token, hence resulting in an invalid token when verifying it.

```
// What caused the error
localStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify(token));
```

Solution, either omit `JSON.stringify`, or parse the token when verifying:

```
localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
// or
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 const token = req.header('token');
 try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(JSON.parse(token), privateKey);
    console.log(decoded)
 } catch(err) {
    console.log('err', err)
 }
```

Comment: Instead of dumping code you should explain your answer.

Comment: Thanks man , didn't noticed this small thing

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, the problem wat at thunderclient, I was sending Authorization header like

> Bearer "mytoken"

, it has to be

> Bearer mytoken

(no double quotes) :D

Answer (score -2):

when you pass token from service convert into JSON.parse(token) from local storage then pass to verify