# jwt.verify keeps on returning invalid signature despite working elsewhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, jwt

I have no idea why, but for some reason the `jwt.verify` function is complaining about an invalid signature in only part of my application. To give you some background, I am trying to set up auth headers using the [context](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#the-context-argument) function with Apollo Server (which I guess is irrelevant anyway as the `jwt.verify` function should work in any javascript code snippet the same way) as follows:

```
context: ({ req }) => {
  const token = req.get('Authorization') || '';

  if (!token) {
    console.log('no token detected. returning null...');
    return { user: null };
  }

  return {
    user: verifyUser(token.split(' ')[1]),
  };
},
```

The `verifyUser` function:

```
const verifyUser = (token: string) => {
  try {
    return jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as Secret);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('error: ', error.message);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Note that I’m following [this guide](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/nodejs-graphql-authentication-with-jwt-apollo-server-mysql-and-sequelize-orm-21cf1503f7f) and have renamed `getUser` to `verifyUser`.

In each graphql request, I am providing a Bearer token, like so:

```
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwczovL2F3ZXNvbWVhcGkuY29tL2dyYXBocWwiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsiYWRtaW4iXSwicGVybWlzc2lvbnMiOlsicmVhZDphbnlfYWNjb3VudCIsInJlYWQ6b3duX2FjY291bnQiXX0sImlhdCI6MTU4NjkwMDI1MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg2OTg2NjUxLCJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NSJ9.31EOrcKYTsg4ro8511bV5nVEyztOBF_4Hqe0_P5lPps"
}
```

But every time I make a graphql request (a query or mutation) in the graphql playground, I am getting an `invalid token` message in the catch block, so presumably the `jwt.verify` function is failing. I wondered whether the JWT I provided to the Bearer code above is wrong, but I do not think it is. I am getting it from an `authenticateUser` resolver:

```
export const authenticateUser = async (
  _: undefined,
  { input: { email, password } }: any
): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByEmail(email);

    if (!user) {
      throw new HttpError(404, 'User not found. Please create an account.');
    }

    const correctPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.hashedPassword);

    if (!correctPassword) {
      throw new HttpError(403, 'Wrong password for this account.');
    }

    // assign object methods to the user instance as objects retrieved from db don't have methods
    Object.setPrototypeOf(user, User.prototype);
    const token = user.signToken(); // see below
    return { token, id: user._id };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new HttpError(error.statusCode, error.message);
  }
}
```

The `user.signToken()` function comes from a `User` class:

```
  signToken(expiry: number | string = 60 * 24): string {
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + this.hashedPassword;
    // { ...this } overcomes error `Expected "payload" to be a plain object`
    const token = jwt.sign({ ...this }, secret, {
      expiresIn: expiry,
    });
    return token;
  }
```

The only difference is that I am passing in a hashed password with the `secret` argument. I’ve also noticed that the error does not occur when using `jwt.sign` instead of `jwt.verify` (like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606341/jwt-gives-jsonwebtokenerror-invalid-token)), but I assume I have to use the verify function.

Does anyone know why my code may not be working? The guide I am following does not pass a hashed password into the secret argument.

Comment: Have you tried it without the hashedPassword (or always with the hashedPassword)? You're using symmetric verification, so it sounds wrong to use different secrets for signing and verifying. The jwt library can't know, what part is the secret and what's the hashed password, so it looks like two different secrets

Comment: Also, always try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, you could check what the actual inputs are to the signing and verification. Then you could remove all API related parts and only leave what seems relevant, ie the signing and verification

Comment: I think my explanation was a bit unclear. In the working part of my app (where it works), I use it with a hashed password (i.e. `const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + this.hashedPassword;`), whereas it's failing where I use it without it (`user: verifyUser(token.split(' ')[1])`), because the Bearer doesn't include the password and I don't think it should either, and as the article's example does it without the hashedPassword. I essentially just need a way to verify that the token is valid so that I can return the user into the context

Comment: It is still not clear to me. From what I understand, you sign the token with `secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + this.hashedPassword` and verify it with `secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET`. I can't imagine this to work for a symmetric algorithm. In the medium article you've linked, they only use the `process.env.JWT_SECRET` to sign (without the hashedPassword)

Comment: I don't know much about JWT tbh. Should you ever sign a token with a hashed password? Maybe when I built `secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + this.hashedPassword` the tutorial I followed was wrong. Is there any harm changing `secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + this.hashedPassword` to `secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no reason to add the hashed password to the secret. Usually you only use the secret to sign and verify tokens

Comment: I'm curious to find this out for sure. I think you're right as it now also works when changing it to remove the hashedPassword. Thank you